# How can I set /etc/network/interfaces to just autoconfigure ipv6?

Tags: ipv6

I have a machine that I just want to run ipv6 on, no ipv4.

I want to use an autoconfigured ipv6 address - I have radvd running on my network and it is working fine.

However there is no config in /etc/network/interfaces that I can set to do that. It supports static ipv6, or if I create an ipv4 address on the interface it will set ipv6, but I dont want to.

Currently reduced to bringing up the interface manually in /etc/rc.local but its messy.

Just want to be able to add "iface eth0 inet6 auto" to /etc/network/interfaces" really.

Answer (score 18):

The magical /etc/network/interfaces keyword when you don't want any configuration is *manual*. If I understand your question correctly, you will want to define eth0 the following way.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
iface eth0 inet6 auto
```

Comment: Thanks, I couldnt find the inet6 auto in the documentation, thats what confused me!

Comment: @user55807 If this answer solved your question, you should click the green check next to it to mark it at solved.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric) was the first release to support the `auto` method on IPv6 interfaces (compare the [11.10 interfaces manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man5/interfaces.5.html) to the [11.04 interfaces manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man5/interfaces.5.html)). If you aren't running 11.10 or later and can't upgrade, your rc.local hack is probably the simplest way, although I seem to recall the DHCP method working on IPv6 interface definitions. This requires a DHCPv6 server, of course.